# How to install multiple .deb files but in specific order with single linux command

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, debian, dpkg

I have 4 debian installer :

```
abc.deb
jkl.deb
pqr.deb
xyz.deb
```

I want to install jkl and xyz first, and then I want to install `abc.deb` and `pqr.deb`. So the sequence/order the .deb files should be installed should be : `jkl.deb` , `xyz.deb`, `abc.deb`, `pqr.deb`.

**PS:**

1. When I am trying to run `apt-get install ./*.deb` it is picking the .deb files in random (or maybe alphabetically) order.
2. So I did `apt-get install ./jkl.deb ./xyz.deb ./abc.deb ./pqr.deb` but still I am seeing that `pqr.deb` is Setting up first before `abc.deb`

Can someone let me know how can i install these four deb in specific order by single linux command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
apt-get install ./jkl.deb && apt-get install ./xyz.deb && apt-get install ./xyz.deb && apt-get install ./pqr.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the installation of packages follows an alphabetical order along with dependencies. So, if you try to install package X and Y but they have A and B as dependencies, the installation order would be: A, B, X and Y.
In your case, you might have to use the following syntax:

```
apt install X && apt install Y
```

Answer (score 0):

*Put \n for new lines (so '\n' between each deb file)

```
list=$(echo -e "abc.deb\njkl.deb\npqr.deb\nxyz.deb")
for i in $list; do apt-get install ./$i; done
```

*or if you use gdebi

```
list=$(echo -e "abc.deb\njkl.deb\npqr.deb\nxyz.deb")
for i in $list; do sudo gdebi $i --n; done
```